# functios in pl sql that returns week in ISO

Tags: function, variables, plsql, message, iso

how to create a simple function in pl sql that contains 2 variables that returns Week in ISO and second varable returns error message that "data was inserted incorrectly" for any table insertion

throw in exception
dbms.output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is that i need to know how to create a function that returns Weeks in ISO and if in the row will be inserted a different type of data should throw an error that specify "wrong data insertion please write corect date" something like that, hope i explain correct)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Please provide sample data for success and error with as much details as possible. Update the question with this info (do no post in the comments). A function takes parameters and returns something - what parameter will you be passing and what should the function return ? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?